# Using php file in HTML video tag containing header location to a video file

Tags: php, html, video, video-streaming

I came up with some weird stuff that I haven't seen before.

I used  `<source type="video/webm" src="test.php">`

instead of `<source type="video/webm" src="example.webm">`

...Test.php file containing only this line of code:

```
header("Location: https://www.example.com/example.webm");
```

and it works..

Is this normal or maybe has some downside for the video/loading/flash(or browser support), is there actually any difference using `test.php` or `example.webm` directly? I am so confused because what I know... this is too good to be true, and too simple. Would appreciate any comment/pointer...

Comment: All that script is doing is sending a redirect to the browser. The browser follows the location to the `.webm` and loads it. The video is not being proxied through your script, nor is the actual location of the `.webm` hidden from the user.

Comment: Thank you... if it is ok to use `test.php` the `.webm` file is not visible inside the code. So I should be able to add some sort of temp token, this would be the idea here.

Comment: Oh.. at least I know now that this approach is pointless.

Comment: @Tom Your comment re:adding a token is correct.  Your comment that it is pointless is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ok to use. The browser just looks for "https://www.example.com/example.webm" when accessing test.php, so the difference in load is very small. (as small as it takes your browser to be redirected).